# how to add slash after every 8 characters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
select 
    custid,
    Stuff(Coalesce('' + t12, '') + Coalesce('' + t11, '') + Coalesce('' + t10, '') + 
          Coalesce('' + t9, '') + Coalesce('' + t8, '') + Coalesce('' + t7, '') + 
          Coalesce('' + t6, '') + Coalesce('' + t5, '') + Coalesce('' + t4, '') + 
          Coalesce('' + t3, '') + Coalesce('' + t2, '') + Coalesce('' + t1, '') +
          Coalesce('' + id, ''), 1, 0, '') AS path
from 
    Table
```

This is the result I get back:

```
431222294701031547005760100001411000302910000718.
```

need to get like this:

```
43122229/47010315/47005760/10000141/10003029/10000718
```

If I use

```
SELECT columns, stuff(Coalesce('/' + t2, '') + Coalesce('/' + t1, '') , 1, 0, '') AS path  
FROM table
```

the result starting like this :

```
/43122229/47010315/47005760/10000141/10003029/10000718.
```

How to fix this? Please help I've been scratching my head from hours....

Comment: sample data please

Comment: stuff(Coalesce('/' + t2, '') + Coalesce('/' + t1, ''), 1,1,'') will work, please try

Answer (score 0):

if the max length of the string is know, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to extract every 8 characters and then concatenate together with "/" inbetween

```
declare @sample table
(
    col varchar(100)
)

insert into @sample (col) select '12345678901234567890123'
insert into @sample (col) select '123456789012345678901234567890'
insert into @sample (col) select '12'


select  s.col, 
        new_col = isnull(col1, '') 
                + isnull('/' + col2, '') 
                + isnull('/' + col3, '') 
                + isnull('/' + col4, '') 
                + isnull('/' + col5, '')
from    @sample s
    cross apply
    (
        select  col1 = nullif(substring(col, 1, 8), '')
    ) p1
    cross apply
    (
        select  col2 = nullif(substring(col, 9, 8), '')
    ) p2
    cross apply
    (
        select  col3 = nullif(substring(col, 17, 8), '')
    ) p3
    cross apply
    (
        select  col4 = nullif(substring(col, 25, 8), '')
    ) p4
    cross apply
    (
        select  col5 = nullif(substring(col, 33, 8), '')
    ) p5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below query

```
SELECT columns, stuff(Coalesce('/' + t2, '') + Coalesce('/' + t1, '') , 1, 1, '') AS path  
FROM table
```

example:

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(max)='/43122229/47010315/47005760/10000141/10003029/10000718'
SELECT STUFF(@txt,1,1,'') as newText
```

This says, starting with the first `1` character position, replace `1` character with nothing ''